# Microsoft Test Management SoapUI integration

Tags: soapui, mtm

We are currently using SOAPUI to test SOAP and Restful API's. We then test our interfaces using Selenium automation tests. Where we are unable to automate or there is no value we test manually.

We are now looking to manage all tests via Microsoft Test Manager, however cannot find how to integrate SOAPUI so the tests reside and report back to Microsoft Test Management.

Has anyone had an experience of:

1. Incorporating SOAPUI with Microsoft test manager
2. SOAPUI and
   other test management tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single unit test in C# using eg the MSTest framework. That test could run the SoapUI tests via the command line.

Benefit: integration

Disadvantage: a single pass/fail result in MTM

How to call soapui tests via the command line: https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html

How to link the MSTest test to MTM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx